# Clear badge from notification center

Tags: objective-c, push-notification

IS there a way to clear the badge count for an app when the user deletes / clears a notification from the notification center? Sorry I am new to this and trying to figure this out. I can clear the badge when the user opens the app but I would also like be able to clear the badge when user deletes the notification from notification center.

Any help would be greatly appriciated

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. 
I found several jail break tricks to do that(http://www.idownloadblog.com/2014/07/08/markasread7/), so i guess this is not possible trought Apple secure way.

Answer (score -1):

Try this in `appDidFinishLaunching`:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0]
```